# Create dll from lib .a in mac?

Tags: .net, macos, dll, mono, lib

How can we create a `dll` file from a `lib` in MAC.

**Context:-** I want create from  `dnsapi.dll` in MacOsX using https://github.com/toots/osx-i586-mingw32/blob/master/i586-mingw32/lib/libdnsapi.a

> **System specifications :-**

```
   MacOs X 10.13.6 (High Seirra)    
   XCode :- 10.1
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/

Comment: Thank you SushilHangover. Creating Bindings with Objective Sharpie requires the knowledge of header file . If We do not have header file, we cannot follow the steps in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/walkthrough?tabs=macos .  like running ` sharpie bind --output=InfColorPicker --namespace=InfColorPicker --sdk=[iphone-os] [full-path-to-project]/InfColorPicker/InfColorPicker/*.h` . Is there a way to link static library without the knowledge of header file.

Comment: If you do not have the header, then you will have to do it by hand based upon the published API that you are trying to use in it.